# create new scope exemplar

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a tabs application. Tab's content I past from the directive with templateUrl :

```
return {
       restrict : 'E',
       templateUrl : 'tab-content.html'
}
```

I can change this content - add new students. But when I push a new tab - changed content displayed. How can I create new tab with initial content?

Here is [example](https://plnkr.co/edit/j1DOXVzq3l3uwKzkGfYa?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Your directive needs it's own scope:

```
return {
   scope: {
      studends: '@',
      grades: '@'
   },
   restrict : 'E',
   templateUrl : 'tab-content.html'
}
```

Maybe consider putting a link function in your directive too.

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Comment: there is empty fields and I can't create a new student when I wrote '@' dependence